# Video: Disable preventing screen lock while playing

Tags: javascript, html, video, screen-lock

I have a site with a decorative autoplaying video and found that it prevents screen lock while playing. While this might be desirable in most cases in this particular case I want the screen to lock as normal since the video is not primary content.

Is there a way to stop the browser from preventing screen lock? Or do I have to pause the video?

Comment: Just a personal opinion, but I despise autoplay videos on any site that isn't a streaming site (and even then it's not always great). For one thing, it can eat cell data allowance on mobile devices in browsers that don't support disabling autoplay. From a UX perspective, it removes a user's control over their own device, causing to a bad experience. Please don't autoplay videos.

Comment: It's more of an animated illustration, think the background of a hero header, and it's intentionally small because it's just decorative (and might even get replaced with an image on mobile devices). But I agree with your general point for "content" videos.